DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR cannot be used to evaluate LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS, use TOOLCHAIN_DIR instead in Xcode
I Am creating another module in my app. So, I first run my project from my Xcode. but it's not built and give me an error.

How can I fix this error?
I Change "LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS" From "DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR" to "TOOLCHAIN_DIR".

And it works but I want to know that is there any other official way to fix this error.
And what is different between "DT_TOOLCHAIN_DIR" to "TOOLCHAIN_DIR"?

I am having the same problem. Where did you change or add to the Library_search_paths?

I changed two files with extension as debug and release. At "pods>firebase>support Files" location.
